# Does docker engine (not Desktop) support Linux containers on Windows 11?

Tags: docker, linux

I've installed docker engine according to the following instructions: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/binaries/#install-server-and-client-binaries-on-windows

I'm trying to run Linux containers on Windows 11, without Docker Desktop:

```
PS C:\> docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started
Unable to find image 'docker/getting-started:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from docker/getting-started
docker: no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.22000 in the manifest list entries.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I believe I'm getting the above error because dockerd is configured for Windows containers:

```
PS C:\> docker info  -f '{{.OSType}}/{{.Architecture}}'
windows/x86_64
```

I've tried to use `DockerCli.exe -SwitchLinuxEngine` however it doesn't seem to have been installed:

```
PS C:\> DockerCli.exe
DockerCli.exe : The term 'DockerCli.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet ...
```

How can I switch to Linux containers?

Comment: From the note inside the provided link:

The following section describes how to install the Docker daemon on Windows Server which allows you to run Windows containers only.

Comment: I'm able to run Windows containers just fine. I need help with **Linux** containers.

Comment: you can't run Linux containers with Docker Binary Installation. Check your provided link.

Comment: I guess my question is not phrased very well, or maybe I'm asking the wrong question altogether. I'll collect my thoughts and be back...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following guide, I'm able to use docker on Windows without Docker Desktop. It may not be exactly true to my original question but meets my use case.
https://dev.to/bowmanjd/install-docker-on-windows-wsl-without-docker-desktop-34m9

Summarising the guide (in case it disappears from the internet):

- Install WSL and check it's version 2: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10#step-2---update-to-wsl-2
- Install a Linux distribution: https://aka.ms/wslstore (I went with Ubuntu)
- Add a non-root user (optional)
- Upgrade any packages to the latest (e.g. on Ubuntu use `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`
- Install docker engine to your Linux distro: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/
- (Ubuntu) Switch over to using iptables `sudo update-alternatives --config iptables`
- (Ubuntu) Add your user to the docker group `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`
- Start the docker daemon `sudo service docker start`
- Run the hello-world container: `docker run --rm hello-world`

*I won't accept my own answer for now, in the hope that someone finds a better way*

Comment: I think the best way to run Linux container in Windows without Docker Desktop is by running it within WSL2 as you have mentioned.